# DockerFile for maven build which have custom Jar

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

WE are creating maven java application which uses custom jar.How can i install custom jar in local maven in docker build context?

Docker file is given below:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine AS build  
COPY Fix43_INTL.jar /app/src
RUN mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/app/src/Fix43_INTL.jar -DgroupId=com.neo -DartifactId=fix43 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean install
COPY ./web-integral-fix-initiator/src /app/src
COPY ./web-integral-fix-initiator/pom.xml /app
RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8  
COPY --from=build /app/target/web-integral-fix-initiator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/web-integral-fix-initiator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Give some extra info. Custom jar is needed during maven's build? What's the issue with the provided dockerfile(errors)? From a quick look, I would place all `COPY` instructions at the beginning.

Comment: If "use custom jar" means that your code needs the maven dependencies as well, then look into how you create a full deployment in Maven.

Comment: yes. we need this Fix43_INTL.jar custome jar during maven build.. we got error when coping custome jar into /app/src : "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, error

> /app/src : "no such file or directory"

is straight forward. You are trying to copy the jar in a path inside the container that does not exist. You should first create the target directory(`/app/src`) and then copy the jar into it.

I edited your dockerfile and made some optimizations(mainly chaining commands in single layer, removed unnecessary `mvn clean install`).

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine AS build
RUN mkdir -p /app/src  
COPY Fix43_INTL.jar /app/src
COPY ./web-integral-fix-initiator/src /app/src
COPY ./web-integral-fix-initiator/pom.xml /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/app/src/Fix43_INTL.jar -DgroupId=com.neo -DartifactId=fix43 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true \
&& mvn clean package

FROM openjdk:8  
COPY --from=build /app/target/web-integral-fix-initiator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/web-integral-fix-initiator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```